# Tous les sens du mot « sardine »

Tags: sens, usage

En jouant aux mots fléchés, je viens de tomber sur un sens de « sardine » qui m'est inconnu. Il y aurait un rapport entre le grade de caporal et le mot « sardine ».

Est-ce que cela vous dit quelque chose ?

Comment: https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/sardine/71012 "Argot militaire. Galon de caporal, de brigadier ou de sous-officier." Je ne vais pas en faire une réponse car il m'a fallu 5 secondes pour taper "caporal sardine" dans google et trouver cette réponse. Il aurait sans doute été plus rapide pour vous de faire pareil.

Comment: Seuls le poisson et le piquet de tente me venait à l'esprit.
merci pour l'information.
Pensez-vous que l'origine de l'expression se situe dans la forme du galon qui ferait penser à une sardine ?

Comment: De rien :-) Bienvenue ici par ailleurs et désolé pour l'accueil un peu abrupt ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A**

La base des informations dans cette section provient du [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sardine).

1/ Il existe donc ce sens du mot non modifié qui signifie « galon », comme le souligne user **Laurent S.**, pour le cas des caporaux, brigadiers et sous-officiers (major, adjudant chef, adjudant, sergent chef, sergent, élève sous-officier) ([réf.1](https://www.dictionnaire-synonyme.com/synonyme-sardine), [réf.2](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grades_de_l%27Arm%C3%A9e_de_terre_fran%C3%A7aise#Officiers)).
(Dans un argot moderne il existe un mot peut-être encore plus suggestif, le mot « frite », qui est utilisé pour les élèves gendarmes pour désigner un de leur galons ; c'est aussi un mot que l'on ne trouve pas dans les dictionnaires pour « galons » mais qui était utilisé comme tel dans l'armée de terre (du moins régionalement), il y a au moins plusieurs décades de cela.)
 On dit aussi « **sardines d'or** » ([réf.](https://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/4621)). De cette dernière référence on peut extraire que « sardine », qui le plus souvent signifie les chevron individuels qui constituent le symbole d'un grade et qui donc s'utilise au pluriel pour référer au symbole du grade (les sardines de sergent), peut aussi s'utiliser au singulier pour référer à l'ensemble des chevrons correspondant à un grade (la « sardine » de sergent).

- 1917 —  Les sous-officiers amenuisaient tellement leur sardine qu'elle pouvait de loin donner le change. source : 1917. Mémoires d'un rat
- 1918 — Ma mère donc eût désiré me voir repartir avec la « sardine » de sergent.

https://www.dictionnaire-synonyme.com/synonyme-sardine

2/ On trouve le terme « **sardine blanche** » ; il s'agit encore de galons mais cette fois ce sont les galons blancs dans la gendarmerie française.

3/ Dans l'expression  « **arroser la sardine** » le mot prend un sens métonymique, où du sens de « galon » il passe à celui de « promotion », cette état de chose étant la cause explicatrice de la possession de galons, la conséquence.

4/  Dans l'expression populaire et vieillie, « **serrer les cinq sardines** », le mot a tout simplement le sens de « doigt de la main ».

5/ Dans le domaine du camping le mot signifie « petit piquet à bout recourbé servant à arrimer une tente au moyen d'une cordelette fixée à la tente en une de ses deux extrémités et en l'autre, au piquet, lequel on enfonce dans le sol ».

**B**

Un symbolisme qui pourrait n'être que superposé, et non le symbolisme originel, a sa source dans une plaisanterie et se limite  à l'image de sardines à l'huile dans leurs boites. Le symbole d'une tête de sardine (et possiblement de sa colonne vertébrale sans chair) n'est donc même pas implicite.

- ([réf.](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/c-est-une-huile.php))  L'origine exacte de cette appelation argotique [(C'est une huile.)] reste obscure.
  Ce qu'on sait, c'est qu'à la fin du XIXe siècle, on disait "nager dans (parmi) les huiles" pour dire "fréquenter des personnes influentes".
  Ce qu'on sait également, c'est que cette appellation vient du milieu militaire où les huiles étaient d'abord les officiers supérieurs.
  C'est pourquoi Cellard et Rey, dans leur Dictionnaire du français non conventionnel, évoquent la possibilité d'une plaisanterie de haute volée.
  En effet, chez les militaires, les galons sont aussi appelés des sardines, et, en dessous des généraux étoilés, plus le grade est élevé, plus le nombre de sardines l'est aussi.
  Or, on sait bien que, dans leurs boîtes, les sardines (qui tuent le temps en se racontant des histoires sans queue ni tête) baignent dans l'huile. Autrement dit, plus le gradé est important, plus il a de sardines, plus c'est une huile.

On trouve la première trace de ce terme, sans texte explicatif, dans un vaudeville en un acte de 1817 ([réf.](http://xn--thtre-documentation-cvb0m.com/content/pr%C3%A9ville-et-taconnet-nicolas-brazier-jean-toussaint-merle#PDF). On sait cependant qu'il était utilisé dans les armées pendant la guerre de 14-18 ([réf.](http://hartmannswillerkopf.e-monsite.com/pages/argot-des-tranchees.html)), en particulier dans les tranchées. C'est un terme d'origine plus ancienne que la guerre de 14-18; on en trouve une trace en 1865 ([réf.](http://www.russki-mat.net/page.php?l=FrFr&a=S)). Dans la même référence on peut trouver la confirmation que c'est la forme de la tête de poisson et son brillant qui suggèrent le terme.

- Sardines (Larchey, 1865) Galons du grade de sous-officier. — Allusion de forme et d’éclat.
  *L’un portait la sardine blanche, L’autre le jaune baudrier.* Nadaud.

Comment: merci LPH et Laurent-s pour ces informations détaillées. A vous lire, je suis impressionnée par la richesse de la langue française. D'ailleurs, j'ai contacté le webmaster du site du jeux [site](https://www.dico-mots.fr/mots-croises/galon+de+caporal.html) pour qu'il étoffe sa fiche avec votre recherche.